# how to fetch the image url from the dataframe and display its my flask template

Tags: pandas, dataframe, flask, jinja2

i have tried to fetch Image from the data frame based on the book title but its does display the image
in my flask template, instead its shows this error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 22:27:37] "GET /A%20Time%20To%20Kill HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 22:27:37] "GET /A%20Time%20To%20Kill HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

here is my get_image_link function where i tried to get the image link based on the book title given

```
def get_image_link(title): 
   df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/suhel/Desktop/book recommendation/file.csv')
   for i in range(len(df.title)):
       if str(title)==df.title[i]:
           idx=i
           get=df.iloc[idx]
           w=get['Image']
           
   return w
```

this is where i have called the  get_image_link and have passed to the flask template

```
 @app.route('/info',methods=['POST'])
    def info():
        if request.method == "POST":
            title = request.form.get('results')
            book_image=get_image_link(title)
            details=get_book_details(title)   
            return render_template('info.html',title=title,details=details,book_image=book_image)
```

this is the  part of the img in my  template

```
<div><br>
                            <img src="{{ book_image }}" alt="Not found" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                        </div>
```

here is my  [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/jirakst/book-recommendation)

Don't know what went wrong ,can u please help me

Thank in Advance

Comment: You should include a few sample lines of `file.csv` to allow us to recreate the problem.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/jirakst/book-recommendation  this is the dataset the i have used it